# execute methods based on radio buttons

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I have two radio buttons with two different ids radio1 id = "choice1"
radio2 id = "choice2"

I want when radio1 is checked, runnig some methods. and when the radio2 is checked run others
But it does not work because I use a void method in a boolean condition. But frankly I do not know how to do otherwise.
Below is my code that does not work.

private void dynamicRadio() {

```
if (this.driver.findElement(By.id("choice1")).click()) {
    verifySelect("idSelect");
    verifyDuree("idDuree");
}

if (this.driver.findElement(By.id("choice2")).click()) {
    verifyDatePicker("idDate");
    verifyTimePicker("idTime");
}
```

}

error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to boolean

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`click()` does not return any status or boolean but *performs* a click. If you want to check if the radio button is checked call `.isSelected()`.

```java
if (this.driver.findElement(By.id("choice1")).isSelected()) {
    verifySelect("idSelect");
    verifyDuree("idDuree");
}

if (this.driver.findElement(By.id("choice2")).isSelected()) {
    verifyDatePicker("idDate");
    verifyTimePicker("idTime");
}
```

Comment: I'm happy if I could help you. In this case you may want to accept this answer or even upvote it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `isChecked()` or isSelected() or you can implement onCheckedChangeListener listener

```
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {

                //handle the boolean flag here. 
                  if(arg1==true)
                         //Do something

                else 
                    //do something else

            }
        });
```

Comment: when i try isChecked it does not work i dont know why !!
    Error :The method isChecked() is undefined for the type WebElement
    But when i try isSelected it works perfectly (even if is a checked button not a selected button)

Thank you for your answer !